# How to fix combination Dutch domain - English uri

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

In Google Webmaster Tools I have 60 non-existing combinations of my Dutch domain and the English original blog. Example:

http://website.nl/enlish-blog

The from English to Dutch translated blog exists.

This problem leads to a degraded customer satisfaction, as Drupal reports the web-page not to be found.

I have checked the Global Redirect property to correct this, and automatically replace the English link with the Dutch link. To no avail.

I tried to correct it in Path redirect, but also to no avail. It is not allowed, because the module interprets it as the redirection of an alias, and advises the alias to be corrected. This does not work, because then the English web-page cannot be found.

My questions:

1. How do I fix this?
2. Why did I get it in the 1st place?

Thanks for any comment or suggestion.

Comment: I'm afraid you will never know what misconfiguration caused this in the first place, unless it still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way of dealing with 404 like that is to use module like [Search 404](https://drupal.org/project/search404):

> Instead of showing a standard "404 Page not found", this module performs a search on the keywords in the URL, e.g. if a user goes to http://example.com/does/not/exist, this module will do a search for "does not exist" and shows the result of the search instead of the 404 page. This should help retain visitors coming in from old URLs linked from other sites or from search indices.

That way user will see a link to an article on a proper domain, if he will enter bad URL.

To prevent creation of "interesting" links it's worth to use [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) - with it even if you will have temporary misconfiguration, users and bots (including Google bot) will get redirected to content's main URL, and that's what will get indexed.

Last but not least, be sure to always set [canonical URL](https://drupal.org/search/site/canonical?f%5B0%5D=drupal_core:87&f%5B1%5D=bs_project_sandbox:0&f%5B2%5D=ss_meta_type%3amodule) for your content, if you care how it looks in search results.

I'm afraid you will never know what misconfiguration caused this in the first place, unless it still occurs. Things to check would be:

1. Canonical URL - are you sure it does not direct everyone to one single domain?
2. [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org) - maybe they have a snapshot from time when your site was actually displaying something under these URLs. If so, you could use backups to unpack a copy on a dev machine, and examine configuration that made this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your interest. I already use Search404 and Global Redirect, and I set the canonical URL. But that does not solve the cause of my problem.

Comment: @HansLodder You asked how to fix it, not how to read Google's mind about their reasons ;p